# How to build & link the Skia library for unity

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, skiasharp, skia

Skia is a graphics library (skia.org). The documentation explains how to build the library after cloning the project via git. But the documentation is unclear as of this date, How to build & link the Skia library for unity